# PHP: Text Processing preg_match function

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, pcre, text-processing

```
<?php
$eqn1="0.068683000000003x1+2.046124y1+-0.4153z1=0.486977512";
preg_match("/\b[0-9]*\b/",$eqn1,$vx1);
echo "X1 is: $vx1[0]";
?>
```

Can someone tell me, how to store the value of x1 (that is, 0.068683000000003) in the variable $vx1?

*The output is:*

```
X1 is: 0
```

Comment: Please paste your code _inline_. Some link to an arbitrary site is _not_ a replacement for that. Thanks.

Comment: And please tell us _what_ error exactly you get. Do not write a question in riddles, give us _all_ details.

Comment: You need to update your regex into `/^[0-9]\.[0-9]*/` inorder to get the value `0.068683000000003`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing semicolons after statements and the echo statement has to be modified:

```
<?php
$eqn1 = "0.068683000000003x1+2.046124y1+-0.4153z1=0.486977512";

preg_match("/\b[0-9]*\b/", $eqn1, $vx1);
echo "X1 is: " . $vx1[0];
```

Comment: [Check this](https://3v4l.org/U829f). Your answer doesn't gives the output that OP has suggested within his question

Answer (score 0):

1)put semicolon after each sentences;
2)use echo "X1 is:" $vx1[0]; instead ofecho "X1 is: $vx1[0]";

```
<?php
   $eqn1="0.068683000000003x1+2.046124y1+-0.4153z1=0.486977512";

   preg_match("/\b[0-9]*\b/",$eqn1,$vx1);
   echo "X1 is:" .$vx1[0];
```

Comment: Please invest some time into propper formatting. Thanks.

Comment: This will return php syntax error "syntax error, unexpected '$vx1' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';'" won't it?

Comment: There is a syntax error in the `echo` command now, the string concatenation requires a `.` between the operands...

Answer (score 0):

Your regex takes into account only integer, your first numùber is a decimal one.

Here is a way to do the job, the number you're looking for is in group 1:

```
$eqn1 = "0.068683000000003x1 + 2.046124y1 + -0.4153z1 = 0.486977512";
preg_match("/^(\d+\.\d+)/", $eqn1, $vx1);
echo "X1 is: ", $vx1[1], "\n";
```

**Output:**

```
0.068683000000003
```