# preg_match() in php: storing the matches in variable

Tags: php

This is the code:

```
<?php
$eqn1="0.068683000000003x1+2.046124y1+-0.4153z1=0.486977512";

if(preg_match("/^[0-9]\.[0-9]{1,}x[0-9]$/",$eqn1,$vx1))
{
echo "X1 is:". $vx1[0];
echo "Match found.";
}
else 
echo "Match not found.";
?>
```

OUTPUT:
    Match not found.

Here, I'm trying to extract the value of x1 (that is,0.068683000000003) and storing it in the variable '$vx1'. It always returns, "Match not found.". What is wrong with my code? If you find any errors, please provide a solution.
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you expect it to match? `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of the string, and your pattern doesn't match there.

Comment: What about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671793/regular-expressions-in-php-extracting-values/37671837 ? Please first close your previous question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex works fine but you have to remove the `^` and `$` char. You also have to put brackets around the group you want to capture.

```
if(preg_match("/([0-9]\.[0-9]*)x[0-9]$/",$eqn1,$vx1))
```

The chars `^` and `$` mean to capture a line only containing the enclosed regex. But your line consist of more then just this number.
If you want to use them any way you have to expand the regex to something like this:

```
^.*="([0-9]\.[0-9]*)x[0-9].*$
```

See here http://regexr.com/3diqc for a working example.

Comment: Also, how to get the values of y1 and z1alone ? I tried the same way and got the value of y1, with 'y1' text following the value in the output. That is, '2.046124y1' and '0.4153z1' respectively. But I want only the values and not values with y1 or z1.

Comment: I've expanded the first example to include the things you want. See here http://regexr.com/3dirj
The point is to enclose the things you need in brackets, this way you capture the parts for later retrieving. And that you don't include y1 or z1 in these groups.
`(\d\.\d*)x\d\+(\d+\.\d*)y1\+(\-?\d\.\d*)z1` replacing `[0-9]` with `\d` makes it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the problem :

```
  <?php
    $eqn1="0.068683000000003x1+2.046124y1+-0.4153z1=0.486977512";

    preg_match("/^[0-9]\.[0-9]{1,}/",$eqn1,$vx1);
    print_r($vx1);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$eqn1="0.068683000000003x1+2.046124y1+-0.4153z1=0.486977512";

if(preg_match("/(?<vx1>^[0-9]\.[0-9]{1,})x[0-9]/", $eqn1, $vx1)) {
    echo "X1 is:". $vx1['vx1']. "\n";
    echo "Match found.";**strong text**
} else  {                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    echo "Match not found.";
}
```

result

```
X1 is:0.068683000000003x1
Match found.array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(19) "0.068683000000003x1"
  ["vx1"]=>
  string(17) "0.068683000000003"
  [1]=>
  string(17) "0.068683000000003"
}
```

**regular error**  : if(preg_match("/^[0-9].[0-9]{1,}x[0-9]**$**/",$eqn1,$vx1))